# JSON parsing issue: Not able to get the correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to parse a JSON in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    j2.[ key ] AS ColumnName,
    CASE
        WHEN j j2.[value] = 'TIMESTAMP' 
            THEN CAST(LEFT(j2.value, LEN(j2.value) - 2) AS bigint)
            ELSE CAST(j2.value AS int)
    END AS LastUpdatedValue
FROM 
    OPENJSON('{
                  "value": {
                    "value": [
                      {
                        "ERDAT": "20221019",
                        "AEDAT": "20221019"
                      },
                      {
                        "ERDAT": "20221104",
                        "AEDAT": "00000000"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }','$.value') j1
 CROSS APPLY 
     OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
 ORDER BY 
     LastUpdatedValue DESC;
```

But I'm getting no results, but no error is thrown, either.

I am expecting the these results:

```
 ColumnName     LastUpdatedValue
---------------------------------
  ERDAT            20221104
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: There are no keys nor values in the JSON that include `TIMESTAMP`. What are you trying to do with the case expression?

Comment: The JSON string is for example only. In real scenarios, there are possibilities to get `TIMESTAMP` as `value`

Comment: In the cases where the value is `TIMESTAMP` then how do you expect to convert `TIMESTA` to a bigint (`CAST(LEFT('TIMESTAMP', LEN('TIMESTAMP') - 2) AS bigint)`)?

Comment: I have edited the OP. can you please now see why I am not getting anything?

Comment: Well I don't see how you're not getting any error messages because there are two syntax errors in the code presented. The first is `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'j2'` because of the random j in `WHEN j j2.[value] = 'TIMESTAMP'`. The second is `Invalid column name ' key '` because of the spaces around `key` in `j2.[ key ] AS ColumnName`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: did you try the above query in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct for parsing the JSON, the path `'$.value'` will not give you the desired output, you need to change it to `'$.value.value'`.

For parsing the string to a number, you can use `TRY_PARSE` like the following.

```
SELECT TOP(1)
  j2.[key],
  TRY_PARSE(j2.[value] as bigint) LastUpdatedValue 

FROM 
    OPENJSON('{
                  "value": {
                    "value": [
                      {
                        "ERDAT": "20221019",
                        "AEDAT": "20221019"
                      },
                      {
                        "ERDAT": "20221104",
                        "AEDAT": "00000000"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }','$.value.value') j1
 CROSS APPLY 
     OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
 ORDER BY 
     LastUpdatedValue DESC;
```

**Output:**

```
key            LastUpdatedValue
----           ---------------- 
ERDAT          20221104
```

Comment: I am getting `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'v' is found at position 13.`