# Not able to parse JSON in synapse SQL with OPENJSON

Tags: sql-server

This question has a reference to my earlier SO thread. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333368/json-parsing-issue-not-able-to-get-the-correct-result/74334473#74334473) it is.

In a nutshell, I am trying to parse a JSON input in Synapse SQL.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json= '{"value": "{\"value\":[{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"}, 
            {\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},"type": "String"}';

DECLARE @ReplacedDetails nvarchar(max), @ReplacedStringDetails nvarchar(max)
SET @ReplacedDetails = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@json)),'\','');
SET @ReplacedStringDetails = REPLACE(@ReplacedDetails,',"type": "String"','');

SELECT @ReplacedStringDetails
    CREATE TABLE #ValueTable_15
        (
        ColumnName varchar(200),
        LastUpdatedValue varchar(200)
        );
INSERT INTO  #ValueTable_15 (ColumnName,LastUpdatedValue)
SELECT TOP(1) j2.[key],TRY_PARSE(j2.[value] as bigint) AS LastUpdatedValue
FROM OPENJSON(@ReplacedStringDetails, '$.value.value') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
ORDER BY LastUpdatedValue DESC;
```

Then when I am running the above query, I am getting error:

```
Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'v' is found at position 13
```

When I am simply trying to `SELECT @ReplaceStringDetails` it is giving the expected results.

What I am missing here?

P.S. I replaced `$.value.value` with simple `$.value`, but yielding no result.

Comment: SQL Server has `ISJSON()` function to check if JSON is well-formed. You can use it to make sure that the **@json** variable holds a legit JSON.

Comment: Strangely this JSON was working earlier. And in Azure SQL the same code is running as expected.

Comment: Your ERDAT data was JSON data embedded in a JSON string. Have you been editing it at some point? Seems like the characters `]}"` got removed before `,"type": "String"}` and so now the JSON data is broken. Deleting the \ characters is a bad idea that will only make matters worse.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments it appears that the characters `]}"` got removed before `,"type": "String"}`. If you correct that edit you should be able to parse the JSON using the normal [`OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) table-valued function, e.g.:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json= '{"value": "{\"value\":[{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"},{\"ERDAT\":\"20210511\"}]}","type": "String"}';

SELECT [embedded].*
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
  [value] nvarchar(max) --nope: AS JSON
) [wrapper]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(wrapper.value, '$.value') WITH (
  [ERDAT] nvarchar(10)
) [embedded];
```

Which returns the results...

| ERDAT |
| --- |
| 20210511 |
| 20210511 |
| 20210511 |
| 20210511 |